# Как с помощью регулярных выражений извлечь одни кавычки и оставить другие?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

```
def yaml(a):
    # your code here
    import re
    b=re.findall(r'(.*:.*)',a)
    bb=re.findall(r'(\w+):\s"?([a-zA-Z0-9\\" ]*)"?',a)
    print('bb',bb)
    count=0
    dic={}
    for i in b:
        s=i.split(': ')
        ss=[]
        for a in s:
            print(a)
            a=re.findall(fr'.*?(\w+\s?\w+).*',a)
            ss.append(a[0])
        print(ss)
        dic[ss[0]]=int(ss[1]) if ss[1].isdigit() else ss[1]
    print(dic)
    return dic


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(yaml('name: Alex\nage: 12'))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert yaml('name: Alex\nage: 12') == {'age': 12, 'name': 'Alex'}
    assert yaml('name: Alex Fox\n''age: 12\n''\n''class: 12b') == {'age': 12,
     'class': '12b','name': 'Alex Fox'}
    assert yaml('name: "Alex Fox"\n''age: 12\n''\n''class: 12b') == {'age': 12,
     'class': '12b','name': 'Alex Fox'}
    assert yaml('name: "Alex \\"Fox\\""\n''age: 12\n''\n''class: 12b') == {'age': 12,
     'class': '12b','name': 'Alex "Fox"'}
```

Не могу удалить кавычки правильно. Например:  "Alex Fox" должно остаться 'Alex Fox' а при "Alex \"Fox\" 'Alex "Fox"'
Как это сделать правильно? Например, bb: это я пробовал извлечь за один раз.
(yaml это просто название)

Comment: Парсить yaml регулярками - очень смело

Comment: yaml ето просто название

Comment: `re.findall(r'"(.*?(?<!\\))"', '"Alex \\"Fox\\"""""\\""')` → `['Alex \\"Fox\\"', '', '\\"']`